# Copy part of a cell contents (with no clear seperator)

Tags: excel, vba

I have a number of 'accounts' for which i would like to create a unique reference code for each. The reference code will be a combination of parts of different cells. So, for example, the reference for the 'account' occupying row 1 would be: cp78925

- The `cp` part is a constant, and will always be the same.
- The `789` part are the last three digits of cell `A1`, which contains a 10 digit code
- The `25` part are the first two digits of cell `B1`, which contains the date on which the account was opened.

So for example:

if `A1 = 1123456789`, `B1 = 25/10/2013` then the unique reference code in `C1`would be = `cp78925`

Searches on the internet show ways of separating the contents of cells by blanks (""), /, after letters etc., or making the last 3 digits BOLD/ITALIC, but I cant work out how to get my specific answer.

Thanks a lot in advance. I hope this is clear enough.

Answer (score 2):

you need something like

<strike>`="CP" & RIGHT(A1,3) & DAY(B1)`</strike>

```
="CP" & RIGHT(A1,3) & TEXT(B1,"dd")
```

Anyway this formula is not going to give you an unique reference if two A1 code ends with the same 3 digits the same day.

```
1234567890 01/01/2013
3213512890 01/02/2013
```

Both will return you `CP89001`

**Edit:**
As reported by Sam092 (thanks), DAY() return a numeric value, TEXT() is the right function to use

Comment: `DAY()` will return only 1 digit for day 01-09

Comment: in addition ... if the business logic becomes more complex than that, I recommend to write a function `CreateKey(p1, p2, p3, ...)` in VBA which often is better to maintain than spaghetti formulas

Answer (score 1):

Formula in `C1`

```
="CP"&RIGHT(A1,3)&LEFT(TEXT(B1,"DD/MM/YYYY"),2)
```

**EDIT:**

I see that you have tagged your question with `VBA`. You don't need vba for this but still if you want a VBA solution then try this

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C1").Formula = _
"=""CP""&RIGHT(A1,3)&LEFT(TEXT(B1,""DD/MM/YYYY""),2)"
```

or

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C1").Value = Evaluate( _
"=""CP""&RIGHT(A1,3)&LEFT(TEXT(B1,""DD/MM/YYYY""),2)")
```